# Add thick vertical line to table using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a table like so. How would I add a thick vertical line between columns 2 and 3 so it splits it in half? I did some searching but everything I found was for a border around an entire column/cell. I just want a line going down.

[image]

Comment: If you are looking for a quick workaround. You could create an additional column between them as wide as you need and fill it with a black background

Comment: Just provide a right border for 2nd column. http://plnkr.co/edit/YD02OT?p=preview using nth-child or just put a class on the tds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use **border**: http://jsfiddle.net/kzp36owo/3/

```
table {
    background: blue;
    color: #ffffff;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
    border-right: 4px solid yellow;
}
```

In order to work properly it's important to reset `cellspacing` of table.